# How to save a username and password to a list in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a desire to make a hub. The hub is account based so you will need log in. How ever I don't understand how to save lists to a file. text.txt:

```
    a = ["tom","password"]
    b = ["james","greensky01"]
```

and  so on... But how can I open these lists and/or print / edit these in the shell.

```
    openFile("text.txt","w")
```

This is the only thing I know how to do.

So how do I make python 3 save the users input to a list in a file?

Comment: Do you want to save multiple users in the same file?

Comment: my main code: [link](https://repl.it/LmoM/1) Easier to show y'all here!

Comment: @Mr.Zeus Yes i do

Comment: What I would do is refer to this tutorial: [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-plain-text-files-in-python-3), though it may be easier to save it into a .py file so you can import it like this: 
`import text.py`

Comment: @Mr.Zeus that tutorial doesn't cover full things, we use "with"keyword while opening file so it takes care of closing of file but that tutorial doesn't talk about this.

Comment: @Mr.Zeus Not really, I just would like to know. To help with future projects

Comment: @Mr.Zeus This tutorial is really confuzing. [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-plain-text-files-in-python-3)

Comment: Sorry @t.madx a can't help you understand the tutorial, but I'm sure there are many more tutorial's on reading and writing files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stores user info into a dictionary. The dictionary is dumped as json to a file after login. The json file is read every time the program starts. If the json file doesn't exist, it will be made.

```
import json

def login(usr):
    uN = input("Name: ")
    pW = input("Password: ")

    if uN in usr.keys():
        if pW == usr[uN]:
            print("Welcome back.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect password.")
            return False
    else:
        print("Hello, new person.")
        usr[uN] = pW

    writeUsers(usr)
    return True

def readUsers():
    try:
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

def writeUsers(usr):
    with open("users.json", "w+") as f:
            json.dump(usr, f)

users = readUsers()
success = login(users)

while not success:
    success = login(users)
```

Comment: The code above gives an error. then immediately closes the window.

Comment: WORKS. However, is there a way to make it so you can create a login - it saves it- then log in with another different , yet saved, account?

Comment: @t.madx Yup. I updated my answer. `login()` checks if the user exists now. If the password is incorrect, it returns `False`. `login()` is now called in a `while` loop, which uses the return values. The loop enables the user to be prompted for login details until he/she either enters the correct password for a user or creates a new account.

Comment: I think this is really helpful and I am using this in my work. @Mark

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

```
a = ["tom","password"]
b = ["james","greensky01"]

with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str((a,b)))
```

i checked your code , it have some errors and Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation, i have modified your code here is working one :

```
a = ["tom","password"]
b = ["james","greensky01"]

login = input("(to login use:\ntom)\n\n>>:")
with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str((a,b)))



if login in a or login in b:
    pasword= input(">>>:")
    if pasword in a and login in a:
        print("You are logged in!")
    elif pasword in b and login in b:
        print("you are logged in!")
    else:
        print("access failed")
else:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: I am not getting your point , are you asking about error in your code or what ? the link you provided that code is not working , showing error.

Comment: it doesn't work rn on that link, if you run the code in python it should work, (on your desktop)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("text.txt","a") as file_:
    file_.write(str(a))
    file_.write(str(b))
```

That puts the logins into the file and closes it automatically.

Then if you want to read the file and check if the username and password match do this:

```
with open("text.txt","r") as file_:
    for x in file_:
        x = eval(x)
        if x[0] == "username user enters":
            if x[1] == "password user enter":
                print("Login Successful")
```

Comment: comes up at invalid  syntax

Comment: Do it now, I messed up the indentation a bit.

Comment: Actually do it now, I should have fixed everything. I'm not testing the code it's all from memory.

Comment: The only reason a and b wouldn't be defined is if you tried to run this code alone without defining the lists.

Comment: oh yeah my mistake